# How to read data from System.in to solve the task?

Tags: java

I'm working on [this item](http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1038). I did the spell checking algorithm but I have no idea how to read data correctly. When I use this:

```
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder(); 
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String temp;
while ((temp = sc.nextLine()).length() > 0){
    text.append(temp);
}

/*spell checking algorithm*/
```

It waits for the empty string.

In this case:

```
while (sc.hasNext()){
    text.append(temp);
}
```

it doesn't continue to execute the code at all. If I try to read 10000 signs I should type it all. 
How could I read data correctly for this task?

Comment: Yes if you want to read the 10000 signs from the User input.The user want to type it all.But you can also use this it to store all the 10000 signs into the file and load it to an HashMap or Array at the time of execution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read them from file:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    //do what you want
}
```

Comment: It's not exactly what I needed but it helped me to find the answer. Thanks